# WPMU Change primary domain

Tags: wpmu

I have a blog network set up with Wordpress and WPMU. I'm trying to change my primary domain from example-foo.com to example-bar.com.

The problem is, when I'm trying to access the website by example-bar.com, I get a redirect loop like this:

```
http://example-bar.com/wp-signup.php?new=example-bar.com
```

This happens when I'm trying to access the website and wp-admin.

I changed the domain by editing the following in the database:

- I changed from example-foo.com to example-bar.com in wp_blogs.
- I changed the domain the same way in wp_options (siteurl and home)
- And in wp_site
- And wp_sitemeta (siteurl)
- And I changed the domain in wp-config.php under define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example-bar.com');

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this further?

Comment: A little late, but did you ever figure this out? I, too, am experiencing this issue. I've updated the domain in all of the spots that you mentioned already, but still getting a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's what you're after but you may want to follow [this tutorial](http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/) on how to change a multi-site primary domain.

Comment: What I'm after? I want to be able to access my site. I followed the steps in the tutorial already, but I still face the redirect issue.